# AngularJS - View Controller and Filter Controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have the following problem:
I have two Views in my AngularJS Applicaiton. One View where I want to display some data and another View where I display my filter for the data View. My question now is, how can I filter the Data?? Normaly I just can say

```
<input type="text" ng-model="f.$"/>
 <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="data in DataArray|filter:f">
      <td>{{data.field1}}</td>
      <td>{{data.field2}}</td>
      <td>{{data.field3}}</td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

so in this example it works because it's the same scope. But how can I make this when I have two independent scopes. So in my example it looks like this:

```
<!-- FILTER VIEW -->
<div ng-controller="filterController">
   <input type="text" ng-model="f.$"/>
</div>
....
....
<!-- TABLE VIEW-->
<div ng-controller="tableController">
 <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="data in DataArray|filter:f">
      <td>{{data.field1}}</td>
      <td>{{data.field2}}</td>
      <td>{{data.field3}}</td>
    </tr>
 </table> 
</div>
```

Comment: most common way is to set up a service to share data between different parts of the app

Comment: yeah I have already done that in both Controllers I added the Service Data, which reads the data from the DB. But also when I do this, is does not work. So how can I filter the Data ?

Comment: are you sharing `f`? Is it an object or a primitve? Create a demo in plunker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That small demo should hepls you [http://jsbin.com/duzaxa/1/edit?html,js,output](http://jsbin.com/duzaxa/2/edit?html,js,output)

```
<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="filterController">
    <input type="text" ng-model="myfitler.$"/>

  </div>
 <div ng-controller="tableController">

 <table>
<tr ng-repeat="data in DataArray|filter:myfitler.$">
  <td>{{data.field1}}</td>
  <td>{{data.field2}}</td>
  <td>{{data.field3}}</td>
</tr>
```

js

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.factory("filterService", function(){

  var _filter = {}
  {

    return {

      filter:_filter

    }

  }

})
app.controller("filterController", function($scope, filterService){

  $scope.myfitler = filterService.filter




})
app.controller('tableController', function($scope, filterService){
  $scope.myfitler = filterService.filter
  $scope.DataArray = 
    [
    {field1:1,field2:"mike",field3:"student"},
      {field1:2,field2:"john",field3:"techer"},
      {field1:3,field2:"tim",field3:"studend"},
      {field1:4,field2:"jessie",field3:"studend"}

  ]

});
```

Comment: thanks it works now. but is that the common way to handle such a problem? or are there better ways ?

Comment: Yes services allows communication between controllers